# QGIS Random points on a gradiant

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to perform the 'Random points....' tools in QGis on a gradiant? For example, I want a polygon to be randomly filled with points with a higher density at the center.

So far all I've managed is to perform the tool a few times in a sort of 'buffer', with lower numbers of points as I move out.

Comment: By what rule, some formula?

Comment: Sorry @BERA, not sure what you mean?

Comment: How do you define "higher density" and "center"

Comment: So I mean more points at a center of a shape or polygon, moving to less points at the edge, still in random places. The center would be the middle of the shape, then centroid.